Not able to install aws-lambda-ric on node:20-alpine base image
I am creating a dockerfile for my nodejs code to deploy on AWS lambda function using docker containers. I am using node:20-alpine base image but not able to install aws-lambda-ric.
this is my dockerfile:
FROM node:20-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache --update --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/ libexecinfo-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    git \
    build-base \
    cmake \
    make\
    autoconf\
    libtool \
    libexecinfo-dev \
    automake\
    python3

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install 

RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric
COPY ./src/* .

CMD ["index.handler"]

And I am getting the error below:
 [7/8] RUN npm install aws-lambda-ric:
39.09 npm error code 2
39.09 npm error path /app/node_modules/aws-lambda-ric
39.09 npm error command failed
39.09 npm error command sh -c ./scripts/preinstall.sh
39.09 npm error libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
39.09 npm error libtoolize: Remember to add 'LT_INIT' to configure.ac.
39.10 npm error *** Do not use buildconf. Instead, just use: autoreconf -fi
39.10 npm error configure.ac:120: installing './compile'
39.10 npm error configure.ac:317: installing './config.guess'
39.10 npm error configure.ac:317: installing './config.sub'
39.10 npm error configure.ac:120: installing './install-sh'
39.10 npm error configure.ac:125: installing './missing'
39.10 npm error docs/examples/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
39.10 npm error parallel-tests: installing './test-driver'
39.10 npm error ./configure: line 6673: syntax error: unexpected ";;" (expecting "fi")
39.10 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-08-05T10_37_40_947Z-debug-0.log

I tried using node:16-alpine base image and it's working with this base image I am able to install aws-lambda-ric.

Please don't use the v.3.16 alpine repository when you use an image using alpine v.3.20. Change that and try again. Since you said "I tried using node:16-alpine base image and it's working", I suppose that's the reason.

I wonder whether the upstream repository has a bug where its Autoconf setup believes /bin/sh is always GNU bash.  This image, with both Javascript and Python interpreters and a full C toolchain, will not be small no matter what you do; does it work better if you switch from an Alpine base to a Debian base?

@DavidMaze clearly, using 4 minor-versions-outdated packages won't do good on any Linux distribution. I do not think this is a matter of which. ;)

@7heo.tk changed the version to v.3.20, getting error :-                                                     ERROR: unable to select packages:
4.359   libexecinfo-dev (no such package):
4.359     required by: world[libexecinfo-dev]

@RajMaurya So I've been looking into this, and there is a non-negligible chance you actually found a bug. I'll keep you posted.

So I'm not done yet, because the bug is in autohell. Of course it's autohell (see points 1 and 5 for what's relevant here) ;)
